# PropTypes checking becomes invalid when I try to remove part of it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I don't know if I have asked it right but I am having error when I try to remove an object inside an array. My array:

```
[{id:"asd-123-sad", text: "hello there", complete: false}, {id:"hgj-456-lop", text: "hello world", complete: false}]
```

Everything is ok when I am adding, I assume at first render it has no value [] or undefined right? These are my errors after delete operation:

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `todos[0]` is marked as required
>   in `TodoList`, but its value is `undefined`.
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

and also when I log my todos, it becomes:

```
[undefined]
```

and when I look inside it, it has:

```
[
0: undefined
length: 1
]
```

I think the problem is by my delete operation because it has length and does that 0 index means it has [{}]? I am not sure. Help?

Comment: `delete` removes a key from an object, but it does not change the array length. So your array has no items, and the length `1`.

Comment: how do you remove the object inside the array? by using splice?

Comment: Show your delete operation please